# "Could not find compatible versions" error on pod install in Github Action Workflow

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

As part of a Github Action workflow (that we are running on a self-hosted runner - a mac-mini) we have a cocoapod install step:

```
- name: Install CocoaPods
  run: bundle exec pod install --deployment
  working-directory: ios
```

However, when this action runs we get the following error:

```
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "mParticle-Apple-SDK":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    mParticle-Apple-SDK (= 8.12.0)

  In Podfile:
    mParticle-Apple-SDK (= 8.12.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `mParticle-Apple-SDK (= 8.12.0), mParticle-Apple-SDK (= 8.12.0)`.
```

I am not able to replicate this issue locally (pods install fine) and I have tried all the advice I can find online, e.g. `pod repo update`, `pod install --repo-update`, deleting the Podfile.lock and regenetating it with a fresh install etc., but no matter what we keep getting the same error about incompatible versions between the Podfile and Podfile.lock (even though they are identical as you can see above).